# O que nossa documentação deve conter?

Tags: debate, big-7

Já faz tempo que discutimos os assuntos que devem fazer parte do nosso foco, o que aceitamos e o que deve ficar de fora.

Agora chegou a hora de começar formalizar um pouco mais. Mesmo que alterações sejam necessárias posteriormente.

Essa é uma das [7 necessidades que todo site deve discutir](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) antes de ser graduado.

Precisamos saber o que colocar no Tour, onde define [o que pode ser perguntado aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [o que deve ser evitado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) e outros documentos relevantes que só o nosso site terá.

A discussão está aberta. Não tenha pressa, não precisamos definir hoje. Precisamos definir bem!

Comment: Uma sessão de chat será agendada para todos participarem para ajudar na discussão. Aguardem!

Comment: Este assunto é mesmo "trabalho para casa"! Para clarificar, o primeiro link aponta para uma versão super resumida daquilo que é visível no [SOEN](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), mas presumo que a resposta a essa parte seja para formular um texto na mesma linha de orientação do que vemos no SOEN!